# Rename multiple files with python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program to rename multiple files at once. This would be through Python, and I realize I'm recreating the wheel but I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Program.......

```
import os

path = "LOCATION"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
myList = []
for x in dir_list:
    if x.endswith(".mp3"):
        f1 = x.split("-")
        ln1 = f1[0]  # Band Name
        ln2 = f1[1]  # Album Title
        ln3 = f1[2]  # Track number
        ln4 = f1[3]  # Song Name
        newname = x.join(ln2 + ln3)
        os.rename(x, newname)
        print(newname)
```

Comment: What's the issue you're encountering?

Comment: line 14, in <module>
    os.rename(x, newname) -> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Comment: It looks like it should be able to find the the file `x` try some [sanity checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check) by printing `x` or the directory, or any other data that could unveil the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
line 14, in <module> os.rename(x, newname) -> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
```

...Is likely due to the path not being included in your `os.rename()` call, I suggest changing `os.rename(x, newname)` to `os.rename(path + x, path + newname)` which will solve that issue.

I also noticed some funky behavior with the way you were grabbing the song information, so if you have any further issues, here's the code I used to debug your original issue which seems to have the result you're going for:

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\Pepe\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\73430533\\"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

for x in dir_list:
    if x.endswith(".mp3"):
        # I ignore the ".mp3" to keep the file names clean
        nameDetails = x.split('.mp3')[0].split('-')

        bandName = nameDetails[0]
        albumTitle = nameDetails[1]
        trackNumber = nameDetails[2]
        songName = nameDetails[3]

        newName = f"{albumName} | {trackName}.mp3"
        print(f"Renaming \"{x}\" to \"{newName}\"")
        os.rename(path + x, path + newName)
```

Comment: I just tried to check for this, but using relative names seems to work, atleast for ubuntu

Comment: I did find some issues with the formatting of new names in their original code, I'll edit my answer to reflect that in case relative names work for their OS/use case